# Include a React app with its own git folder in git repository

Tags: git

I have two applications I want to include as part of the same repository. An Express backend and a React frontend. The React frontend was created using `npx create-react-app`. Creating a React app in this way also creates a `.git` folder and a `.gitignore` file in the folder of my React app. After running `git init` on the parent folder of what I want to include I am left with a repository that contains two `.git` folders:

```
.git
.gitignore
README.md
react-frontend
    .git
    .gitignore
    README.md
express-backend
```

After attempting to add files to the repository with `git add .` git warns me about the second `.git` folder:

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> youtube-dl-react-frontend
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached youtube-dl-react-frontend
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

I am not sure what to do here. What is a submodule and is it really what I want to use to include my React app? Or should I just delete the `.git` folder from the React folder? Or is there something different I should be doing here?

I also tried commiting, then running `git push -u origin master` to see if I would be able to push my changes, but I was unable to:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'my project url'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: you can set the frontend directory as a submodule if you treat it as a separate project (then it can have its own remote and people in your team can work on it without to have the backend). If you treat the backend and frontend as a single project, then you can delete the .git in the frontend folder. For the second question try to do a git pull first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A git folder contains git config files and commits and all changes in git repository if you want to make your project directory work with your own git repository delete the .git folder that react made for you and then use
`Git init`
`Git remote add origin (repo url)`
`Git add .`
`Git commit -m "your message"`
`Git push -u origin master`

Comment: I can't delete the .git file . I'm getting error like this : "rm: cannot remove '.git': Is a directory"

Comment: @VELDASRDURAI You Have To Use rm -rf Command For Deleting A Directory

Comment: This does not work with git hub using the commands given.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted Answer no longer works or potentially never did because you cannot push your commits onto an existing branch of a new repo
most of it is good until you actually push:

```
> git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
```

is the main thing that joins the local branch to the remote repo's main

```
> ... git@github.com:{org}/{repo}.git
```

is an ssh repo connection

start here:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:{org}/{repo}.git 
git add .
got commit -m "init"
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
```

now merge your .gitignore file (keeping the react generated one) and any others you please.

```
git add .                                                       
git commit -m "save me jebbers"
git push
```